# What does an L mean at the end of the salary in India?

Tags: india, terminology, salary

In the following job ad in India, what does the L mean at the end of the number?

Expert level Data Engineer
Bengaluru
₹15L – ₹20L

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It means [lakh](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh), a multiplier of 100,000. So these numbers are equivalent to 1.5-2 million Indian Rupees.

Comment: And at the current exchange rate, this is somewhere in the range of $18,000 to $24,000.